# MFC VC++ zoom in zoom out CDC Objects i.e Crect and Lines on the Canvas with Cscrollview support

Tags: windows, visual-c++, graphics, mfc, zooming

I am trying to implement zoom in zoom out functionality in VC++ MFC framework.As I am new for this facing problem in CDC, Graphics And CscrollView concepts.

Default ZoomLevel is 100%  and it's scaling by 20% up/Down (60,80,**100**,120,140,160).

As I have to Zoom the CRect (i.e some rectangular blocks) along with that some lines which is connected to that Rectangle.

Currently Able to zoom with scrollbar support using Cscrollview but while we zoom at some level for ex. 120% I am expanding canvas size 
canvas default page size vertically and horizontally are i.e  5000.
Now while we zoom @120% (canvas size * 120) i.e 6000.

Anyhow after zooming blocks and inside image all are expands properly at all zoom level. But the main problem is Connecter With that rectangle block are 
not exactly connected to center its showing some gap.

For that I am attaching one image which showing gap between Block and Connector line.

Before Zoom @ default level i.e 100% which looks properly connected:
[image: BEFORE]

After Doing zoomin i.e @120% Lines are not connected properly to the Blocks:
[image: AFTER]

As you can see Before and after Zoom rectangle and lines objects showing some gap.That is required to be fixed after doing zoomin/out.

Please let me know, What should be best practise or how to expand/zoom the canvas and its all the objects on it ?

Is there any way if we expand or zoom the view/canvas bitmap object all the object(CREct + Lines + images etc on that canvas also adjusted accordingly?

My requirement for zoomin/zoomout is similar like windows print preview dialog box is providing **DefaultView Zoomin and Zoomout** option at diffrent level (100,125,150,200 etc).

Or if you have any project reference code related to this please share it will be very big help for me.

Comment: What is THE question?

Comment: Thanks Michal And Ajay for taking interest,
Images are separate that is showing before zoom and after zoom scenario.
And The question is same like after zooming that blocks lines are not exactly connected 2 center of blocks as like before zoom image.

Comment: It's very hard to answer your question without seeing the code, and I suppose the code is too large to be posted here. There may be multiple reasons for this behaviour. It may be related to rounding problems.

Comment: Thanks for your Ans @MichaelWalz,

My main question is in MFC Document/View Architecture,
Is it like if we expand or zoom the view/canvas, and 
all the bitmap objects on the canvas like (CREct + Cpen etc ) also adjusted or take position 
properly?

Comment: After having a closer look it appears that the grey lines are not scaled at all. What does the 200% zoomed picture look like?

Comment: Yes @MichaelWalz you are absolutely right,
actually The Rectangular Block i am  resizing and inside image also but 
how to find exact scaling ratio between Cpen line objects and that block ?
that is the challenge i ma facing...bcz Line object have start point and end point(start.X,end.Y)

And the gap is increses/Decreased @200% zoom level and decres @50% vice-versa.

if you have some code project or demo for reference plz let me know 

Thanks & Regards,

Comment: Sorry this question just too broad for a Q/A site.